# Getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error message on 1 of 4 background image loads within same code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have created 4 buttons named cell1, cell2 cell3 and cell4
I am attempting to set the background image in the following for loop.
Cells 1, 2 and 4 load successfully with the background image.
I received the following message for cell3.
All cells were created the same, the tag for each button was set 1, 2, 3 and 4.

I am a loss as to why cell3 (button) does not load.  I have reviewed similar previously answered question on this topic but am drawing a blank.

Here is the code that is failing:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    UIButton *cellIndex = (UIButton *)([self.view viewWithTag:i]);
    NSLog(@"==> viewDidLoad cellIndex1 = (%i)", cellIndex.tag);
    [cellIndex setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L0background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
}
```

Here is the results for the background load:

```
2013-08-30 09:50:07.898 match[863:11f03] ==> viewDidLoad cellIndex1 = (1)
2013-08-30 09:50:07.899 match[863:11f03] ==> viewDidLoad cellIndex1 = (2)
2013-08-30 09:50:07.899 match[863:11f03] ==> viewDidLoad cellIndex1 = (3)
2013-08-30 09:50:07.900 match[863:11f03] -[UIView setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d68230
2013-08-30 09:50:07.901 match[863:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setBackgroundImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7d68230'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1912012 0x1695e7e 0x199d4bd 0x1901bbc 0x190194e 0x27bf 0x6bb1c7 0x6bb232 0x60a3d5 0x60a76f 0x60a905 0x613917 0x22f5 0x5d7157 0x5d7747 0x5d894b 0x5e9cb5 0x5eabeb 0x5dc698 0x277ddf9 0x277dad0 0x1887bf5 0x1887962 0x18b8bb6 0x18b7f44 0x18b7e1b 0x5d817a 0x5d9ffc 0x202d 0x1f55 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Comment: I think that is a UIButton method, UIView is a not a subclass of UIButton.

Comment: you could use a UIImageView... if it doesn't need to respond to button presses, or a button, if it does.

Comment: `[self.view viewWithTag:i]` is returning something that isn't a `UIButton` so casting it to `UIButton` is pointless. Try something like `NSLog(@"view : %@", NSStringFromClass([[self.view viewWithTag:i] class]));` this will print the class as a string to the console. Also please can you provide all the relevant code, clearly you haven't provide all the code since it is crashing at the method call `setBackgroundImage:forState:` and that isn't included in the code provided.

Comment: You can also do checks like `if([[[self view] viewWithTag:i] respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forState:)]) { }` This if statement makes sure the object that is returned responds to the selector that it crashes at. You can also do `if([[[self view] viewWithTag:i] isSubclassOfClass:[UIButton class]]) { }` This will check to see if the returned view is actually a `UIButton`.

Comment: Obviously, one of those items is not a UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Your cellIndex is declared inside the `for` loop. Its local to the `for` loop. You are trying to set a background image outside the `for` loop where it has no knowledge of cellIndex object. Have you declared a cellIndex object outside that `for` loop? 
If not, then you will have to set the background image inside your `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks but I screwed up the cut & paste - I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear: `[self.view viewWithTag:i])` is returning an `UIView` instead of an `UIButton` when `i` is 3.
You can verify that yourself by adding `NSLog(@"Returned view: %@", cellIndex)` just below that line. This log will also show which view is returned. You can then use that information to identify the culprit. I suspect that there's another view in the view hierarchy with 3 as tag. Double-check your XIBs/Storyboards to make sure the only view that has 3 as its tag is your button.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  I found the view with the duplicate tag and corrected it.  Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, if you want to help other people struggling with this issue to find this answer faster please accept and/or upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, `UIView` does not respond to the method in question. The object at index 4 is not a UIButton.

To help guard against this crash, do this:

```
UIButton *buttonObject;
for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    id cellIndex = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
    if ([cellIndex isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        buttonObject = (UIButton *)cellIndex;
        NSLog(@"==> viewDidLoad cellIndex1 = (%i)", cellIndex.tag);
        [buttonObject setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"L0background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not a button, returned %@",[cellIndex class]);
    }
}
```